# Angular: IE11 When using an Multiple Select element, ng-repeat on options with ng-mouseover fails to trigger method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, internet-explorer

**Backstory:** I want to display a little more information on an option element inside of a select box. The way I planned about doing this was to hover over an option and display more information about that option below, and this works! :)

**The Problem:** While this works in every other browser except IE (I tested this issue in IE11), however, it appears as though IE won't trigger the event at all. I tried different ng-{events} here and nothing appears to work. I want to know if there is a workaround for this, or possibly a different way of solving this problem. I created an example of the issue. Be sure to test it in IE11 (this is the browser I need it to work in unfortunately). Why IE WHYYY!!!? :(

**Note** I am looking for an angular solution. :)

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('ngrepeatSelect', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
     hovered: '',
     model: null,
     showExtraInformation: function (option) {
       this.hovered = option.health;
     },
     clearExtraInformation: function () {
       this.hovered = '';
     },
     availableOptions: [
       {id: '1', name: 'Option A', health: 'Great Health :)'},
       {id: '2', name: 'Option B', health: 'Bad Health :('}, 
       {id: '3', name: 'Option C', health: 'Ok Health :|'}
     ]
    };
 }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-select-ngrepeat-production</title>
  

  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  
  <style>
    select {height: 100px; width: 200px;}
  </style>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="ngrepeatSelect">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <form name="myForm">
      <label for="repeatSelect"> Repeat select: </label>
      <select multiple name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.model">
        <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" 
          value="{{option.id}}" 
          ng-mouseover="data.showExtraInformation(option)"
          ng-mouseout="data.clearExtraInformation()">{{option.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <tt>model = {{data.model}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>
      hover = {{data.hovered}}
    </tt>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Best bet is to use a UI library (like Kendo UI or UI Bootstrap) that reimplements dropdowns instead of letting the browser render normal select elements.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that, kinda wanted that to be my last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer...

**Underlying Problem:** After some reading, IE does not support events on the "option" element. For example, (click, mouseover, mouseout, change, blur, etc).

Based on JC Ford's response, I decided to solve this problem using checkboxes in angular material. I chose not to use a "material multiple select" since the behavior of the UI is not particularly what I or the client is expecting, however, if you wanted to go down that path, I did test it and it does work with these events...

Attached is my solution.

***Note:*** the solution doesn't show the checkboxes, material doesn't want to show up here. Not sure why, but if you put it into your application, it works.

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])

    .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.selected = [];
      $scope.hovered = '';
      $scope.model = null;

      $scope.items = [{
          id: '1',
          name: 'Option A',
          health: 'Great Health :)'
        },
        {
          id: '2',
          name: 'Option B',
          health: 'Bad Health :('
        },
        {
          id: '3',
          name: 'Option C',
          health: 'Ok Health :|'
        }
      ];

      $scope.showExtraInformation = function(option) {
        $scope.hovered = option.health;
      };

      $scope.clearExtraInformation = function() {
        $scope.hovered = '';
      };

      $scope.toggle = function(item, list) {
        var idx = list.indexOf(item);
        if (idx > -1) {
          list.splice(idx, 1);
        } else {
          list.push(item);
        }
      };

      $scope.exists = function(item, list) {
        return list.indexOf(item) > -1;
      };

      $scope.isIndeterminate = function() {
        return ($scope.selected.length !== 0 &&
          $scope.selected.length !== $scope.items.length);
      };

      $scope.isChecked = function() {
        return $scope.selected.length === $scope.items.length;
      };

      $scope.toggleAll = function() {
        if ($scope.selected.length === $scope.items.length) {
          $scope.selected = [];
        } else if ($scope.selected.length === 0 || $scope.items.length > 0) {
          $scope.selected = $scope.items.slice(0);
        }
      };
    });
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-select-ngrepeat-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.5/angular-material.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" class="md-padding demo checkboxdemoSelectAll" ng-app="MyApp">
    <fieldset class="demo-fieldset">
      <legend class="demo-legend">Using md-checkbox with the 'indeterminate' attribute </legend>
      <div layout="row" layout-wrap="" flex="">
        <div flex-xs="" flex="50">
          <md-checkbox aria-label="Select All" ng-checked="isChecked()" md-indeterminate="isIndeterminate()" ng-click="toggleAll()">
            <span ng-if="isChecked()">Un-</span>Select All
          </md-checkbox>
        </div>
        <div class="demo-select-all-checkboxes" flex="100" ng-repeat="item in items">
          <md-checkbox ng-checked="exists(item, selected)" ng-click="toggle(item, selected)" ng-mouseover="showExtraInformation(item)" ng-mouseout="clearExtraInformation()">
            {{ item.name }}
          </md-checkbox>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <hr>
    <tt>model = {{selected}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>
      hover = {{hovered}}
    </tt>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In IE 11 blur event  is triggered before mousedown , So check if present Element and target element are same then return or else do scroll  FUNCTIONALITY something

Inside Blur Event

```
bind("blur", function(e) {
 var tarElement = event.relatedTarget ? event.relatedTarget : nextElement;
       if (tarElement.id === iElement.attr('id')) {
           return;
       } else {
           CALL scroll 
       }
```

Comment: Not quite what I am looking for, if you notice, this is a mouseover, not a mousedown.